# Expeption in HttpUrlConnection.connect() for android emulator

Tags: android, exception, connection, port, emulation

I am writing an android app that should connect to a Web Service I wrote, but every time I try to test it on the emulator I get this error when the app enters in the HttpUrlConnection.connect() line: heres my code. The exception thrown is java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8080): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused). Thank you in advance to anyone that can resolve this problem.

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Log.d ("8","entered into doInBackground");
        String Content;
        try
        {
            // Defined URL  where to send data
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("function","getData");
            json.put("id", 1);
            conn.connect();
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write( json.toString() );
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            Content = conn.getInputStream().toString();
            return Content;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d ("9","entered into do in background exception");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }


    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String Content) {

        try {

            readJsonStream(Content);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ReadPositionJSONFeedTask", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access your PC localhost from Android emulator, use 10.0.2.2 instead of 127.0.0.1.

> **10.0.2.2**:
>   Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

Reference: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: I had some problems in understanding how I should proceed: in my code I ask a connection to a similiar URL : "http:/localhost:8080/ ecc...". Do mean I should change the localhost in this URL to 10.0.2.2? because it's not working and th log I receive is java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2:8080/...

Comment: Yes, instead localhost:8080 or you should use 10.0.2.2:8080. To make a quick test, you can open the browser in the emulator and open http://10.0.2.2:8080. If you receive an answer the issue is in your code, otherwise something is not right in your web server.